# Sybase ASA 8 character issue - £ vs ú

Tags: sybase-asa

I have an issue at a client where the same data field displays differently in our legacy application installed on two different machines. The character in question is the UK pound sign £ which on some machines displays as ú.

I have tried to over-type this character with £ on machines where it's wrong, but this then "breaks" it on machines where it was working correctly before.

Oddly this issue has started to spread to other machines even though there has been no changes to the application for several years, and the client assures me that no new software or updates have been applied to them. The displaying of the fields value is consistent on all connections to the database, ie. through our application, Interactive SQL and Crystal Reports 8, 9 & 10.

All client machines are connecting via ODBC to the same ASA 8.0.2.4234 database server service over TCP/IP.

Comment: You can find out what the value of the character is by using the ASCII function on the correct part of the string.

If the same then it is due to the character set you are displaying the results in

Answer (score 1):

The Sybase ODBC clients will almost certainly be using different character sets.  Without knowing a bit more about your application it is difficult to know where the wrong character set is being picked up, but you can override the character set in use when you set up the ODBC data source.

[image: ODBC Charset]